# field type for True/False/Empty

Tags: entities

I have a field on a content type which is an optional override for another field. I want the value to only be either 0, 1, or empty, the last meaning "no override". What field type should I use for this? I was looking at a select list for a good user experience, but I was unable to get empty as a value in the list.

I also need another field that can only have values "img", "txt" or "". How should I accomplish this? I want to avoid having users type in "img" or "txt" in case they misspell it.

Comment: I asked about [similar thing](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74419/how-to-add-tri-state-checkboxes-to-form-created-with-form-api) and I'm in (damn slow) process of making a module for it. Just FYI. There is no ready made tri-state control in Drupal now, except lists with 3 values (or not-required ones with 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select lists have always the option `None` if they are not set as *Required*. That said, you can create a *List (Text)* field  with select list widget and set only two options, `0` and `1`, and you will get the `None` option automatically.